# ViewFlipper switching ListViews via Gesture

Tags: android, listview, gesture, viewflipper

I have a `FiewFlipper` that has ListViews as children. I have looked for a way to intercept touch events for a `GestureDetector` before they reach the children - a method to globally intercept touch events over the ViewFlipper.

Extending FiewFlipper and implementing `onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)` seemed to be the solution. This works well for most children. However, when the listview **begins to scroll**, onInterceptTouchEvent stop receiving the events.

I know it's possible to set each listview's  OnTouchListener, but this ruins simple hierarchy I'm attempting to create.

Comment: The behavior you're trying to suppress is intentional and you probably shouldn't try to fight it. `ListView` invokes the method requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) when it begins scrolling, which prevents touch event dispatch from invoking onInterceptTouchEvent on that view's ancestors. It does this so that sloppy scrolling gestures do not get interrupted while the user is trying to scroll.

Comment: You need to return `true` from `onInterceptTouchEvent` to redirect the touch events from the `ListView` to your own component (ie should actually do anything when intercepting except deciding whether the redirect the event or not). You can do this once the user moves their finger too far left/right. This way you never have both components actually acting on the touch events at the same time.

Comment: See this class for an example implementation http://www.jmstudio.org/ - it also has dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by adamp, this behaviour is intentional and does not need to be fought. I applied the gesture listener to the children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I once had an activity with a single listview, where I re-populated the adapter as a result of fling gestures. I did it by implementing the dispatchTouchEvent method of the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

The listview still received the normal events, but my gestureDectector got to taste them too. Perhaps a similar approach will work for you?

Comment: You should always return true if the event was handled. Your example should probably do something like: `boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev); handled |= gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); return handled;` This also isn't the recommended approach for tracking things like this, you should really use `onInterceptTouchEvent`. As I described in my comment to the question, the behavior described is intentional.